# How do I access Json data in Coldfusion

Tags: json, coldfusion

I am getting 20 random images from Flickr from the search. I need to get the results - in this case the images, into a Coldfusion structure so that I can insert it into a database table.

1. I would like to add a dynamic search term - i.e. "cats" and when the page loads then the results are returned. With the code below you have to enter the search term and click the search button.
2. I need to get the image url in a coldfusion variable.

I do not know how to access the data with Coldfusion.

```
<input id="searchterm" />
<button id="search">search</button>
<div id="results"></div>
<script>
  $("#search").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
    {
      tags: $("#searchterm").val(),
      tagmode: "any",
      format: "json"
    },
    function(data) {
      $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).prependTo("#results");
        if ( i == 20 ) return false;
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You will have to forward the clientside response (`data`) to your own server using AJAX. How you do it, depends on the requirements. You might not want to trust a clientside forward, so you are probably better off requesting the Flickr API serverside as well, i.e. forward the search terms (`$("#searchterm").val()`) instead of the response and then request these serverside.

Comment: If you want the data in colfusion, then you'd want to do this server side, rather than in javascript.